# Filtros que dependen de Otros

Tags: django

Primero que nada no se si este sea el titulo correspondiente a mi pregunta, si alguien sabe como se llama esto que estoy tratando de buscar se lo agradecería para cambiar el nombre de la pregunta

tengo estos modelos:

```
class TipoMascota(models.Model): 
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
descripcion = models.TextField(blank = True)    
def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre

class Raza(models.Model): 
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
descripcion = models.TextField(blank = True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.
```

En **TipoMascota** van Perros y Gatos
y en Raza van **Labrador Retriever**, **Gato Persa**, **Pastor Alemán**, entre otros.

hay alguna manera de que cuando yo seleccione por ejemplo Perro en TipoMascota y después vaya a seleccionar la **Raza** Solo me aparezcan las Raza de los perros y no la de perros y Gatos juntos? en el **Admin** de Django.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]